# Unable to retrieve name and number using contact ID

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve contact's name and number using the id stored in database, but the cursor returns `false` when trying to `cursor.moveToFirst()`. Here's the code -

```
Log.d(TAG, id);
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
        new String[]{id}, null);
if(cursor == null){
    return;
}
while (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    try{
        number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        number = "";
    }
    try{
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        name = "No name";
    }
}
cursor.close();
```

Note - the ids are correct. I've checked using log statements.

The execution directly skips to `cursor.close()` after initializing the cursor. On debugging and checking, I found that thewhile statement fails as `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

> cursor.moveToFirst() returns false means there no data matched with ur
>   query. For conformation check cursor.getCount() to check the data is
>   having or not.